# Create Wall / Barrier Using SKSpriteNode physicsBody

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skphysicsbody

I have a separate "Floor" class in my SKSpriteKit application. When I first created this class, I had a barrier around the whole frame using

> self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

but that was actually stopping SKSpriteNodes from entering from the top of the screen so now I'm trying to figure out how I can create a left, right and bottom of the frame wall but not the top. This is so I can avoid one of my SKSpriteNodes at the bottom of the screen (still viewable by users) that moves left and right from leaving the display. I'm trying below which is building as if it's going to work but then when I start up the game I don't see the the walls? I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong, I have

> skView.showsPhysics = true

```
    import Foundation
import SpriteKit

    class Floor: SKNode {
        override init() {
            super.init()

            let leftWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height))
            leftWall.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
            leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size)
            leftWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
            self.addChild(leftWall)

            let rightWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height))
            rightWall.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
            rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size)
            rightWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
            self.addChild(rightWall)

            // Set the bit mask properties
            self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = balloonCategory
            self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = nailDropCategory
            //self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = balloonCategory
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemted")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the scene size and scale mode? I.e. you are positioning these Sprite nodes at 100,100 and 200,200, are you sure that is within the visible portion of your scene? Also, not the main problem but: you are assigning a physics body to the scene twice and it can have only one, so add the physicsBodies to the sprites, I.e not "self.physicsBody=" but "leftWall.physicsBody=".

Comment: Turn off gravity for your walls

Comment: basically you want to do `leftWall.isDynamic = false`

Comment: @AliBeadle I have to use “self.physicsBody” cause it’s a separate class rightv

Comment: No. Each SKNode (and SKScene is an SKNode) can have at most one Physics body. By creating two physics bodies and applying them to the same node (it is not clear, but I assume your code is part of your SKScene) then you are effectively losing the first one. So as well as KnightOfDragon's solution to your main problem (and I think he is correct) I think you will also need to look into moving your physics bodies elsewhere. The normal place for them is on the nodes that they affect - i.e. your SKSpriteNodes.

Comment: You know what's wrong below @AliBeadle ?

Answer (score 2):

Gravity is affecting your walls, so they are forever falling into oblivion.

When you created your edge loop, you did not need to worry about this because edge loops are always static because it has no volumne

Now you are using volume based bodies, so you need to account for things like gravity and other forces affecting your bodies.

To have your body ignore these forces, simply set `isDynamic = false`

```
let leftWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height))
leftWall.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
leftWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: leftWall.size)
leftWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
self.addChild(leftWall)

let rightWall = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.brown, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: frame.height))
rightWall.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
rightWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rightWall.size)
rightWall.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false
self.addChild(rightWall)
```